# complex angular ngrx effect with confirmation dialog in middle of chain

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, ngrx, ngrx-effects

So I have simple process of deregistering clients from policy.

My deregister action should:

1. based on selected clients from list fetch all clients data based on theirs ids
2. after fetching data from point 1, show confirmation dialog with all of this data
3. on dialog you can add/remove some of previously selected clients
4. after confirming dialog send modified clients list to deregister process

my action starts with:

```
export class DeregisterClients implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.DEREGISTER_CLIENTS;

  constructor(public policyNumber: string, public ids: number[]) {
  }
}
```

So the question is how effect should look like?
Below only pseudocode and map operator used everywhere as I dont know which operators should be used

```
  @Effect({dispatch: false})
  deregister$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<DeregisterClients>(DEREGISTER_CLIENTS),
    // 1 fetch all data
    map(event => {
      return event.ids.map((id) => {
        return this.api.fetchClient(event.policyNumber, id);
      });
    }),
    // 2 collect all data from point 1 and show this data in dialog
    map((insureds) => {
      return this.dialogService.open(DeregisterDialog, data: {policyNumber: 'TODO', clients}}) //here i lost policy number :(
        .afterClosed();
    }),
    // 3 check result after dialog closed
    map((result: DeregisterDialogResult) => {
      if (!result.success) {
        return [];
      }
      return result.clients.map(client => this.api.deregister("TODO", client));//here i lost policy number :(
    }),
    //4 concurrently deregister them
    //todo
  );
```

Maybe it is just too complex? But from businness perspective it is one action.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Is it proper apporach to build such complex effect, if so  which operators should be used in points 1/2/3/4

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference.

You can create one effect, or split the effect chain in multiple smaller effects reacting to each other. For example, an effect dispatches the action "Step 1 Completed", a second effect listens this action and react to it.